# Can't access EKS cluster from CodeBuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-eks, aws-codebuild, eksctl

Already saw this particular post [kubectl error You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized) when accessing EKS cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50791303/kubectl-error-you-must-be-logged-in-to-the-server-unauthorized-when-accessing) and followed some guides from AWS but still no success..

I'm creating a CI/CD pipeline. But CodeBuild is apparently not authorized to access the EKS cluster. I went to the specific CodeBuild role and added the following policies:

- AWSCodeCommitFullAccess
- AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess
- AmazonS3FullAccess
- CloudWatchLogsFullAccess
- AWSCodeBuildAdminAccess

Also created and added the following policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "eks:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Afterwards I executed the following command in the terminal where I created the EKS cluster: `eksctl create iamidentitymapping --cluster <my_cluster_name> --arn <arn_from_the_codebuild_role> --group system:masters --username admin`

And checked if it successfully added to aws-auth by running the command `kubectl get configmaps aws-auth -n kube-system -o yaml`. It returned:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  mapRoles: |
    - groups:
      - system:bootstrappers
      - system:nodes
      rolearn: arn:aws:iam::********:role/*********
      username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
    - groups:
      - system:masters
      rolearn: arn:aws:iam::*****:role/service-role/*******
      username: ******
  mapUsers: |
    []
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2021-11-10T07:37:06Z"
  name: aws-auth
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: *******
  uid: *********
```

Still I get the error it's unauthorized.. Below is the buildspec.yml file:

```yaml
version: 0.2
run-as: root

phases:

  install:
    commands:
      - echo Installing app dependencies...
      - chmod +x prereqs.sh
      - sh prereqs.sh
      - source ~/.bashrc
      - echo Check kubectl version
      - kubectl version --short --client

  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon EKS...
      - aws eks --region eu-west-2 update-kubeconfig --name <my-cluster-name>
      - echo Check config
      - kubectl config view
      - echo Check kubectl access
      - kubectl get svc

  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Push the latest image to cluster
      - kubectl apply -n mattermost-operator -f mattermost-operator.yml
      - kubectl rollout restart -n mattermost-operator -f mattermost-operator.yml
```

EDIT:

Running the command `kubectl config view` in CodeBuild returns:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://**********eu-west-2.eks.amazonaws.com
  name: arn:aws:eks:eu-west-2:**********:cluster/<cluster_name>
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: arn:aws:eks:eu-west-2:**********:cluster/<cluster_name>
    user: arn:aws:eks:eu-west-2:**********:cluster/<cluster_name>
  name: arn:aws:eks:eu-west-2:**********:cluster/<cluster_name>
current-context: arn:aws:eks:eu-west-2:**********:cluster/<cluster_name>
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: arn:aws:eks:eu-west-2:**********:cluster/<cluster_name>
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      args:
      - --region
      - eu-west-2
      - eks
      - get-token
      - --cluster-name
      - <cluster_name>
      - --role
      - arn:aws:iam::*********:role/service-role/<codebuild_role>
      command: aws
      env: null
```

Running the command `kubectl config view` in the terminal where I created the EKS cluster returns:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: ***********eu-west-2.eks.amazonaws.com
  name: arn:aws:eks:eu-west-2:*******:cluster/<cluster_name>
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: *********eu-west-2.eks.amazonaws.com
  name: <cluster_name>.eu-west-2.eksctl.io
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: arn:aws:eks:eu-west-2:*******:cluster/<cluster_name>
    user: arn:aws:eks:eu-west-2:*******:cluster/<cluster_name>
  name: arn:aws:eks:eu-west-2:*******:cluster/<cluster_name>
- context:
    cluster: <cluster_name>.eu-west-2.eksctl.io
    user: ******@<cluster_name>.eu-west-2.eksctl.io
  name: ******@<cluster_name>.eu-west-2.eksctl.io
current-context: arn:aws:eks:eu-west-2:********:cluster/<cluster_name>
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: arn:aws:eks:eu-west-2:*******:cluster/<cluster_name>
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      args:
      - --region
      - eu-west-2
      - eks
      - get-token
      - --cluster-name
      - <cluster_name>
      command: aws
      env: null
      interactiveMode: IfAvailable
      provideClusterInfo: false
- name: ******@******.eu-west-2.eksctl.io
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      args:
      - token
      - -i
      - <cluster_name>
      command: aws-iam-authenticator
      env:
      - name: AWS_STS_REGIONAL_ENDPOINTS
        value: regional
      - name: AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
        value: eu-west-2
      interactiveMode: IfAvailable
      provideClusterInfo: false
```

ANYBODY IDEAS PLS? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GOT IT!

I used the role that CodeBuild created automatically.. But by creating a new role with the mandatory policies and edit this in CodeBuild, those steps above will succeed..
If anyone can further explain this that would be great!