# Cannot create namespaces in AWS Elastic Kubernetes Service - Forbidden

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-iam, kubectl, amazon-eks

I am trying to host an application in **AWS Elastic Kubernetes Service(EKS)**. I have configured the EKS cluster using the AWS Console. Configured the Node Group and added a Node to the EKS Cluster and everything is working fine.

In order to connect to the cluster, I had spin up an EC2 instance (Centos7) and configured the following:

**1. Installed docker, kubeadm, kubelet and kubectl.**
**2. Installed and configured AWS Cli V2.**

To authenticate to the EKS Cluster, I had attached an IAM role to the EC2 Instance having the following AWS managed policies:

**1. AmazonEKSClusterPolicy**
**2. AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy**
**3. AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly**
**4. AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy**
**5. AmazonElasticContainerRegistryPublicReadOnly**
**6. EC2InstanceProfileForImageBuilderECRContainerBuilds**
**7. AmazonElasticContainerRegistryPublicFullAccess**
**8. AWSAppRunnerServicePolicyForECRAccess**
**9. AmazonElasticContainerRegistryPublicPowerUser**
**10. SecretsManagerReadWrite**

After this, I ran the following commands to connect to the EKS Cluster:
**1. aws sts get-caller-identity**
**2. aws eks update-kubeconfig --name eks-cluster --region ap-south-1**

When I ran **kubectl cluster-info** and **kubectl get nodes**, I got the following:

[image]

[image]

However, when I try to run **kubectl get namespaces** I am getting the following error:

[image]

I am getting the same kind of error when I try to create Namespaces in the EKS cluster.
Not sure what I'm missing here.

> Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "namespace.yml": namespaces is forbidden: User "system:node:ip-172-31-43-129.ap-south-1.compute.internal" cannot create resource "namespaces" in API group "" at the cluster scope

As an alternative, I tried to create a user with Administrative permission in IAM. Created **AWS_ACCESS_KEY** and **AWS_SECRET_KEY_ID**. Used **aws configure** to configure credentials within the EC2 Instance.

Ran the following commands:
**1. aws sts get-caller-identity**
**2. aws eks update-kubeconfig --name eks-cluster --region ap-south-1**
**3. aws eks update-kubeconfig --name eks-cluster --region ap-south-1 --role-arn arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:role/EKS-Cluster-Role**

After running **kubectl cluster-info --kubeconfig /home/centos/.kube/config**, I got the following error:

[image]

> An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:user/XXXXX is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:role/EKS-Cluster-Role

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue??

Comment: who create the cluster? the same user can add you to the cluster in eks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this issue. Earlier I created the AWS EKS Cluster using the root user of my AWS account (Think that could have been the initial problem). This time, I created the EKS Cluster using an IAM user with Administrator privileges, created a Node Group in the cluster and added a worker node.

Next, I configured AWS Cli using the **AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID** and **AWS_SECRET_KEY_ID** of the IAM user within the Centos EC2 instance.

Just like before, I logged into the Centos EC2 instance and ran the following commands:

**1. aws sts get-caller-identity**
**2. aws eks describe-cluster --name eks-cluster --region ap-south-1 --query cluster.status** (To check the status of the Cluster)
**3. aws eks update-kubeconfig --name eks-cluster --region ap-south-1**

After this, when I ran kubectl get pods, kubectl get namespaces, There were no more issues. In fact, I was able to deploy to the cluster as well.

So, as a conclusion, I think we should not be creating an EKS cluster using the root user in AWS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check your cluster role binding or user access to EKS cluster

```
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: eks-console-dashboard-full-access-clusterrole
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - nodes
  - namespaces
  - pods
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
- apiGroups:
  - apps
  resources:
  - deployments
  - daemonsets
  - statefulsets
  - replicasets
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
- apiGroups:
  - batch
  resources:
  - jobs
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: eks-console-dashboard-full-access-binding
subjects:
- kind: Group
  name: eks-console-dashboard-full-access-group
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: eks-console-dashboard-full-access-clusterrole
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Check the config map inside the cluster having proper user IAM mapping

```
kubectl get configmap aws-auth -n kube-system -o yaml
```

Read more at :https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-kubernetes-object-access-error/

Comment: I am not able to run the command: **kubectl get clusterrolebinding**.

Error: 

**Error from server (Forbidden): clusterrolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io is forbidden: User "system:node:ip-172-31-43-129.ap-south-1.compute.internal" cannot list resource "clusterrolebindings" in API group "rbac.authorization.k8s.io" at the cluster scope.**

Comment: check configmap and update the user details

Comment: I have updated the question with additional findings as well. Can you please have a look?

Comment: I cant get the configmaps as well.