# User cannot log into EKS Cluster using kubectl

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

I am trying to host an application in **AWS Elastic Kubernetes Service(EKS)**. I have configured the EKS cluster using the AWS Console using an **IAM user (user1)**. Configured the Node Group and added a Node to the EKS Cluster and everything is working fine.

In order to connect to the cluster, I had spin up an EC2 instance (Centos7) and configured the following:

**1. Installed docker, kubeadm, kubelet and kubectl.**
**2. Installed and configured AWS Cli V2.**

I had used the **AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID** and **AWS_SECRET_KEY_ID** of user1 to configure AWS Cli from within the EC2 Instance in order to connect to the cluster using kubectl.

I ran the below commands in order to connect to the cluster as user1:

**1. aws sts get-caller-identity**
**2. aws eks update-kubeconfig --name trojanwall --region ap-south-1**

I am able to do each and every operations in the EKS cluster as user1.

However, I have now create a new user named '**user2**' and I have replaced the current **AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID** and **AWS_SECRET_KEY_ID** with that of user2. Did the same steps and when I try to run '**kubectl get pods**', I am getting the following error:

[image]

> error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)

Result after running **kubectl describe configmap -n kube-system aws-auth** as user1:

```
Name:         aws-auth
Namespace:    kube-system
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Data
====
mapRoles:
----
- groups:
  - system:bootstrappers
  - system:nodes
  rolearn: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:role/AWS-EC2-Role
  username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}


BinaryData
====

Events:  <none>
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create an EKS cluster, only the user that created a cluster has access to it. In order to allow someone else to access the cluster, you need to add that user to the aws-auth. To do this, in your `data` section, add

```
mapUsers: |
  - userarn: arn:was:iam::<your-account-id>:user/<your-username>
    username: <your-username>
    groups:
      - systems:masters
```

You can use different groups, based on the rights you want to give to that user.

If you don't already have a config map on your machine:

1. Download the config map `curl -o aws-auth-cm.yaml https://amazon-eks.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cloudformation/2020-10-29/aws-auth-cm.yaml`
2. Replace default values with your values (role arn, username, account id...)
3. add the mapUsers section as described above
4. from terminal execute `kubectl apply -f aws-auth-cm.yaml`

You can also follow steps from the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html)  (it's more detailed)

Comment: Hi, This worked. I logged into the cluster as user1 and ran **kubectl edit -n kube-system configmap/aws-auth**. Added the above code which you had provided. Gave the user ARN of **user2** against **userarn**, **username: admin** and saved the Configmap. Then, I tried to log into the EKS cluster using user2 and it worked. Thanks!